# Can't get the Hough circles

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I have the following image:

[image]

I'm using opencv 3 in c++, and the following code always returns 0, no matter what I try to do with the thresholds.

```
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
cv::Mat img; // this is an image i've loaded... I'm not showing this code here

cv::HoughCircles(img, circles,
    cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 1, 100, 100, 0, 0);

int n = circles.size();
```

I'm guessing I have a small mistake but I can't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to invert image. `HoughCircles` expects white edges on black background.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but same result :\

Comment: houghCircles internally computes sobel and canny, so inverting doesnt matter, but it would be better if the circle was filled! Is your image grayscale (8UC1)? One problem is definitely that your min/max thresholds for canny are identical. Try `cv::HoughCircles(img, circles, cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 1, 150, 50, 0, 0);` instead

Comment: It's all about parameters. Play with them, use different values.

Comment: @Micka Thank you it works better now. But I'm confused. The [documentation]() says that one of them is `: Upper threshold for the internal Canny edge detector` and one is `Threshold for center detection.`. They don't look like the min and max of the same value... Anyway, you can write an answer so I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the second param isnt for canny. I always make that mistake...! Play a bit with those parameters! Canny param should be nice at 100 but center accumulator might be too big.